# How can I use an array texture in threeJS?

Tags: three.js, textures, shader

Is there a way to send an array texture from ThreeJS to my shader? I know one example using Data2DTextureArray, but I would like to send an image.

Comment: Use [DataTexture](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/textures/DataTexture) to map raw data to texture. [Usage example](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=frame#webgl_framebuffer_texture)

Comment: ...that would be one way - but I do have images uploaded by users that I need to package to the data texture.